# Dropdownlist in masterpage value not updated after new selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages

I would like some help with the following problem. I have a dropdownlist implemented in my masterpage. It has an sql data source from which it loads the values of companies. Depending on which value(company) selected, it shows that value in a label on a different page. 
The ddl which is in the masterpage is ofc still visible and should display the selected value which it does at the 1st time a value is selected. But when i select another value in the ddl it shows the value which was 1st selected and so on. So it doesn't update or something.
My code:

This is the onselectedIndexChanged event handler:

```
protected void DropDownListType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        String input1 = DropDownListType.Text;
        String input2 = DropDownListType.SelectedValue;
        String url = "~/test.aspx?pcompany="+input1;

        DropDownListType.SelectedValue = input2;

        Session["Company"] = input2;

        Response.Redirect(url);

    }
```

and this is the code i'm using in my Page_load method from the masterpage:

```
if (Session["Company"] != null)
{
    DropDownListType.SelectedValue = (String)Session["Company"];
}
```

If I remove this last piece of code from my page_load method it updates the label with value on the redirected page but it resets my ddl to default value instead of keeping it at 4 when value 4 selected.

I hope this is a bit clear to you all. Any help is appreciated. Ty in advance.

Comment: you need to look at the page life cycle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting the label value in the PreRender() method. The problem you're having is with the page life cycle. I would change your OnLoad method to use

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
    if (Session["Company"] != null) 
    {
        DropDownListType.SelectedValue = (String)Session["Company"];
    }
}
```

This way you're only setting it once when the page loads and from then on the page will set the selected value automatically using viewstate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm surprised i didn't try it myself yet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `Load` event is fired before the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, that's why you don't have it set in `Session` yet.

See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

just set the AutoPostback property of the DropDownList to true and then it will work.
This is because otherwise the onselectedIndexChanged will be called only on PostBack from a button or any other field.
And also, as the above answer says, use this code:

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
    if (Session["Company"] != null)
    {
        DropDownListType.SelectedValue = (String)Session["Company"];
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't the problem he's having.